# adding and subtracting in a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'd like to start by saying that I am still new to JavaScript and this is a CodeWars Kata **Number of people in the Bus.**

Also I know there is a simpler way of completing this task but If I just googled the answer, I feel that I wont have learned anything so here goes:

Hi All,
at the end of a loop, how do I get it to add a, minus b on repeat? what is that called?

i.e.

```js
[ 10, 0, 3, 5, 5, 8 ]
```

should work math like:

```js
[ 10 - 0 + 3 - 5 + 5 - 8 ]
```

it's a codewars kata and I know there is a simple way of doing it but I have gone around it the long way.

Here is the code I am up to (and the console.log that is the test case)

```js
var number = function (busStops) {
  let newBusStops = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < busStops.length; i++) {
    newBusStops = newBusStops.concat(busStops[i]);
  }
  //   return newBusStops;
  let passengers = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < newBusStops.length; i++) {
    passengers += newBusStops[i];
  }
  return passengers;
};
// var number = function (busStops) {
//   let passengers = 0;
//   for (let i = 0; i < busStops.length; i++) {
//     passengers += parseInt(number[i]);
//     busStops.toString();
//     return busStops;
//   }
// };

// var number = function (busStops) {
//   for (let i = 0; i < busStops.length; i++) {
//     return busStops[i][0] - busStops[i][1];
//   }
// };
// return busStops[0][0];

console.log(
  number([
    [10, 0],
    [3, 5],
    [5, 8],
  ])
);
console.log(
  number([
    [3, 0],
    [9, 1],
    [4, 10],
    [12, 2],
    [6, 1],
    [7, 10],
  ])
);
```

I've managed to flatten the 2d array but I am only able to add the flattened array, I can't figure out how to do `add a minus b`. I don't know what that is called so I can search it

Comment: Why did you decide to flatten the array? The structure as is makes sense in that you have `[+a, -b]` in every entry.

Comment: I flattened it a 2d array was a new concept to me and I couldn't get the loop to work with the 2d array

Comment: Try to do it with the 2d array. Your second `for` loop is a good place to start. Inside the loop, you would have another array with two numbers in them, e.g. `[10, 0`]. Add the first number and subtract the second number from `passengers`. Try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go through the array with a counting index (like you do). Depending on this index, I would add or substract the value from the last result.

**First Hint**: Loop over an array with key-value pairs like this

```
for (const [key, value] of array) {console.log(key, value);}
```

**Second Hint**: A subtraction is a addition with a negativ number

```
5-3 == 5+(3*-1)
```

**Third Hint**: Have a look at the modul Operator **%**

```
console.log(1%2);
console.log(2%2);
console.log(3%2);
```

**Solution:**

```js
 var number = function (busStops) {
   var total = 0;

   for (const [i, value] of busStops){
  total += value*(i%2?1:-1);
   }
   return total;
 }
```

Comment: [Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Good point, thx :)

Comment: ok, I've got it. Let me change it

Comment: @Marcus, Thank you for your help, the MODULO was a fantastic idea where it checks for what position the loop is in the array and the 'Ternary' does either the addition or subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Though I suggest that you first try to solve your Kata by yourself, I'd like to present some solutions based on your code and an alternative solution with the `reduce` method.

### 2d array and `for` loop.

You were on the right track with this one. The only thing missing was that you weren't adding or subtracting from any number. Besides that `return` statement stopped the loop before you could complete your calculations.

```js
var number = function (busStops) {
  let passengers = 0;
 
  for (let i = 0; i < busStops.length; i++) {
    passengers += busStops[i][0] - busStops[i][1];
  }
  
  return passengers;
};

console.log(
  number([
    [10, 0],
    [3, 5],
    [5, 8],
  ])
);

console.log(
  number([
    [3, 0],
    [9, 1],
    [4, 10],
    [12, 2],
    [6, 1],
    [7, 10],
  ])
);
```

### Flattened array with `for` loop and `%`

As suggested by @Marcus, you could use a modulo operator to see if you're in an even or odd iteration in the loop and therefor decide wether to add or subtract. Also, flattening can be done with the [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method that every array has.

```js
var number = function (busStops) {
  let passengers = 0;
  const flattenedBustStops = busStops.flat();
   
  for (let i = 0; i < flattenedBustStops.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      passengers += flattenedBustStops[i];
    } else {
      passengers -= flattenedBustStops[i];
    }
  }
  
  return passengers;
};

console.log(
  number([
    [10, 0],
    [3, 5],
    [5, 8],
  ])
);

console.log(
  number([
    [3, 0],
    [9, 1],
    [4, 10],
    [12, 2],
    [6, 1],
    [7, 10],
  ])
);
```

### 2d array and `reduce`

With the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method you can loop over your array and change the output completely. In this case we pass a starting value of `0`, which is our accumulator `acc`. Then we loop over each entry in the array, add, and subtract the values before returning the accumulator. This method can get complicated pretty fast, but makes a lot of sense with this scenario.

```js
const number = (busStops) => 
  busStops.reduce((acc, [add, remove]) => 
    acc += add - remove
  , 0);

console.log(
  number([
    [10, 0],
    [3, 5],
    [5, 8],
  ])
);

console.log(
  number([
    [3, 0],
    [9, 1],
    [4, 10],
    [12, 2],
    [6, 1],
    [7, 10],
  ])
);
```